# Smoothing spline with dependent coordinates in R

Tags: r, splines, gamlss

I have a series of patients in whom I have measured the value of a certain blood quantity at several time points. However, the time points vary a lot and the number of measurements range between 2 and 5. I would like to fit a smoothing spline to a graph were I have each patient's blood values on the Y-axis and time on the X-axis. I would like to have a graph like the one shown below

[image]

I am using R, and with the `smooth.spline` function I can have a smoothing spline with all data-points used, but I think I should consider each patient's data points as dependent and hence I cannot put them just to a two vector.

How could I produce a smoothing as shown above?

Comment: Apparently I should be using generalized additive models. I was wondering how I can feed have several linear models to gam() function. Each patient has own characteristic linear model (as shown in picture) and I cannot consider all patient together thus ignoring within-patient variations.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest, it may be that generalized additive models are suitable, but you may need something more general.

If the individual variation is just noise around a common underlying population model, a GAM sounds quite sensible.

However, if, as you seem to be suggesting) individuals have some variation in underlying curves (i.e. not simply noise about a common curve), you would usually use *mixed models*, so if you think you need GAMs, but with capacity for individual variation in curves, you may want *generalized additive mixed models* (GAMMs). e.g. see the R package `gamm4` and the `random` and `re` functions in `gamlss`.

(Another possibility would be some kind of semiparametric model with a mixed parametric term - e.g. you might use something like that for parallel curves, for example. You might need something like a semiparametric model because of the issue where they all are measured at different times)